# How to fix error when using caret::varImp?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to find varImp for the following model,

> Linear Discriminant Analysis
>
> 50 samples 25 predictors  2 classes: 'L', 'Lpo'
>
> No pre-processing Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation  Summary
> of sample sizes: 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, ...  Addtional sampling using
> SMOTE
>
> Resampling results:
>
> ROC        Sens       Spec
> 0.9433345  0.9439082  0.8942777

caret::varImp(result$models[[2]], scale = TRUE)

Is there an easy fix for this error:

```
Error in y - mean(y, rm.na = TRUE): non-numeric argument to binary operator
Traceback:

1. caret::varImp(result$models[[2]], scale = TRUE)
2. varImp.train(result$models[[2]], scale = TRUE)
3. filterVarImp(x_dat, y_dat, nonpara = nonpara, ...)
4. apply(x, 2, testFunc, y = y)
5. FUN(newX[, i], ...)
```

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVRrp.png)

Comment: its hard to help you without knowing what `result$models[[2]]` is. It would be much easier if you posted a reproducible example with an inbuilt data set.

Comment: I did provide result$models[[2]] in the quotation box starting from Linear Discriminant Analysis. Is that not enough?

Thank you so much for even replying by the way, this has been quite a pressing issue for me that I have spent countless hours on.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. You need to provide code how you created the object, preferably with an inbuilt data set.

Comment: Hm ok, I am not sure I am able to share too much as that is above my paygrade to decide. But I will see what I can add to my post in the meantime.

Comment: just use an inbuilt data set like [`Iris`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/datasets/versions/3.6.2/topics/iris) or [`Sonar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlbench/versions/2.1-3/topics/Sonar) and post a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment by @Zyad Shehadeh and @missuse you have to `dput` some data or reproduce your error with an in-built dataset. When I tried to reproduce your situation (that you didn't explain very well), with the `iris` dataset, all it works: I assume that you are running a classification (due to the `method="lda"`) with an imbalance dataset (due to the `additional sampling SMOTE`). I simulate this kind of data with `iris`:

```
library(caret)

data("iris")
#eliminate a level in the Species column and reduce the observation for Species="versicolor" from 50 to 10 to imbalance the outcome 
iris <- iris[-c(1:90),]
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species,levels = unique(iris$Species))
cn <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV",sampling="smote",classProbs = T,summaryFunction = 
twoClassSummary)
fit <- train(Species~.,data = iris,trControl=cn,method="lda",metric="ROC")

caret::varImp(fit, scale = TRUE)
```

And all it works, so the problem is somehow related to your data and not to the code

Comment: Thank you for this insight.